# Drawing a disk inside canvas issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

this is my jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/RS29j/

The ball is never showing and i guess it's from clearing the canvas in the update function :

```
 function Update() {
     // ...
     if (ball.y + ball.vy >= 184) {
         ball.y += ball.vy;
     // ...
```

my purpose is to create a simple gravity where the user hit the up button and the ball go up and down again to it's initial position can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You might need to do a `-=` in there

Comment: where ? can u show me please

Comment: final location or keydown up, it depends on what the game should achieve.

Comment: Remember that moving up is reducing y axis

Comment: I am doing a simple gravity when the user hit the up button the ball should go up and fall down again to it's initial position

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46309/discussion-between-sora-and-julio)

Comment: Your suspicion is right, your problem is from clearing the canvas, but in combination with the fact that you never redraw the ball at all in your update function and that to go up, you need to subtract from the Y axis. Do a call to draw at the end of the update function and change the += to -=, and you will have a ball going up in increasing steps on your screen.

Comment: I tried that and the ball started to bounce infinitly and that is not what i am looking for

Comment: @Sora Your question was why the ball was never showing. I told you how to fix that issue.